# Edit background slide music in Powerpoint 2016

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I have downloaded a Powerpoint template from the internet.

When I play the slides, a piece of audio plays automatically everytime a new slide comes on. I am struggling to find the option to edit this. I am not sure whether I want to edit this background audio or remove it altogether.

Can anybody help me find these options please? I am not pressing a button for the audio to play, it is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

#### Can anybody help me find these options please?

> **Delete a music clip or another sound in PowerPoint**
>
> To delete a music clip or another sound in PowerPoint, do the
>   following:
>
> - Locate the slide that contains the sound that you want to delete.
> - In Normal view, click the sound icon Audio clip icon or CD icon Icon, and then press Delete.
>
> To re-add an audio clip, see [Add or delete audio in your PowerPoint
>   presentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-audio-in-your-PowerPoint-presentation-c3b2a9fd-2547-41d9-9182-3dfaa58f1316).

The link above explains how you can **edit** existing audio including transitions that happen when you change slides.

Source [Delete a music clip or another sound in PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delete-a-music-clip-or-another-sound-in-PowerPoint-5eb21c03-23ea-4eb5-9317-db9ec3d1970e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: This is the issue, there is no audio clip icon to delete. It is a blank side, but when you play it it plays a sound, as if the audio is embedded in the slide somehow.

Comment: @al_sweets Did you try the instructions in the quoted link? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-audio-in-your-PowerPoint-presentation-c3b2a9fd-2547-41d9-9182-3dfaa58f1316

Comment: The sound might be included as part of a transition, in which case there won't be an icon. Go to the slide that plays the sound, click the Transitions tab and check to see if anything's listed next to "Sound:" in the Timing group.